# Fullcalendar custom css with Vue3 and postcss

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3, vue-cli, postcss

I am using fullcalendar with vue3. I want to change change colors for button and text in fullcalendar.

**vue version**

```
"vue": "^3.2.26",
```

I am getting error

> Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-custom-properties requires
> PostCSS 8.

I am following steps mentioned in [fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization).

**fullcalendar-vars.css**

```css
:root {
  --fc-border-color: green;
  --fc-button-text-color: #ff0000;
}
```

I have installed following packages

```json
"postcss": "^8.4.7",
"postcss-calc": "^8.2.4",
"postcss-custom-properties": "^12.1.4",
"postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
```

Added **postcss.config.js** at root

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      require('postcss-custom-properties')({
        preserve: false, // completely reduce all css vars
        importFrom: [
          'client/fullcalendar-vars.css' // look here for the new values
        ]
      }),
      require('postcss-calc')
    ]
  }
```

And my **vue.config.js** as follow

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "./client/main.js",
    },
  },
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/dist"),
};
```

Also I would like to know, Do I need make any changes in vue.config.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PostCSS error

Vue CLI scaffolded projects [already include PostCSS](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#postcss) (including `postcss`, `postcss-calc`, and `postcss-loader`), so you don't need to install it in your project. The only dependency needed here is `postcss-custom-properties`.

To resolve the PostCSS error, you should uninstall the PostCSS dependencies that you had mistakenly added:

```js
npm uninstall --save-dev postcss postcss-calc postcss-loader
```

### Starting from scratch

To setup custom colors for FullCalendar in a Vue CLI scaffolded project:

1. Install `postcss-custom-properties` with:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev postcss-custom-properties
   ```
2. Create `postcss.config.js` with the following PostCSS configuration:

   ```js
   // <projectRoot>/postcss.config.js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       require("postcss-custom-properties")({
         preserve: false,
         importFrom: [
           "client/fullcalendar-vars.css",
         ],
       }),
       require("postcss-calc"),
     ],
   }
   ```
3. Create `fullcalendar-vars.css` with the following CSS:

   ```css
   /* <projectRoot>/client/fullcalendar-vars.css */
   :root {
     --fc-border-color: green;
     --fc-button-text-color: #ff0000;
   }
   ```

   **Note:** Changes to this file are not hot-reloaded, so the **dev server must be restarted** to reflect any updates.
4. Start the Vue CLI dev server with:

   ```
   npm run serve
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-fullcalendar-customize-colors?file=client%2Ffullcalendar-vars.css)